# product ampleness

Tags: algebraic-geometry

let X a smooth relative projective scheme over a normal basis S. Let $\{(Y_i,L_i)\}_{i=1,2}$ be schemes with relatively projective morphisms $Y_i\rightarrow X$ induced by ample line bundles $L_i$ on $Y_i$. Assume that $L_i^{d_i}$ is very ample for $d_i\geq r_i >0$ and that $r_1\geq r_2$. Is it true that $(L_1\otimes L_2)^d$ is very ample on $Y_1\times_X Y_2$ for $d\geq r_1$? If it helps we can also assume that $Y_i=Proj_A(\cal{E})$ for $\cal{E}$ a finitely generated $\cal{O}_X$-algebra.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are too many irrelevant hypothesis in your question. Consider a very ample invertible sheaf $F_i$ on $Y_i$ relatively to $X$. Then $F_1\otimes F_2$ is very ample on $Y_1\times_X Y_2$ relatively to $X$ by Segre embedding. This holds for any scheme $X$.